# C pointer accept wrong address inside the loop

Tags: c

i wrote a function for rotate matrix in 90 degree.
the strange thing is when i initial the pointer inside the loop the address are wrong after couple iterations, when i do it inside the loop all work good.
anyone can please explain it?

working like this:

```
int* p1, *p2, *p3, *p4;
for (level = 0; level < (matrixSize / 2); level++) { //loop goes as number as matrix frames

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) { //loop swap inside the frame

        p1 = matrix + (matrixSize * level) + level + i; //first element
        p2 = matrix + (matrixSize * level) - level + last + i * matrixSize; //last element first row
        p3 = matrix + matrixSize * last - (i * matrixSize) - (matrixSize * level) + level; //first element last row
        p4 = matrix + (size - i) - (matrixSize * level) - level;
```

not working like this:

```
int* p1, *p2, *p3, *p4;
for (level = 0; level < (matrixSize / 2); level++) { 

    p1 = matrix;
    p2 = matrix;
    p3 = matrix;
    p4 = matrix;

for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {` //loop swap inside the frame
    p1 = p1+ (matrixSize * level) + level + i; //first element
    p2 = p2+ (matrixSize * level) - level + last + i * matrixSize; //last element first row
    p3 = p3+ matrixSize * last - (i * matrixSize) - (matrixSize * level) + level; //first element last row
    p4 = p4+ (size - i) - (matrixSize * level) - level; //last element
```

Comment: Please post a proper [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: After the first iteration, what happens to your pointers? In the next iteration, your p1 is pointing to a different location compared to the first iteration. Don't try array type arithmetic with pointers. Pointers point to different locations in different iterations of the loop, you've to modify your arithmetic accordingly.

Comment: after couple iterations it points to an address outside the matrix. why the pointers point to different direction after the iterations ? is i initial the pointer every time inside the loop is it the right way?

Comment: You are using `i` to select an offset from the beginning of the matrix.  If you want to choose an offset based on the previous offset, then you probably shouldn't be involving `i`.

Comment: Consider this `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) a = 5 + i` and `i = 5; for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) a = a + i`. That's what is happening in your two code snippets, more or less. See how the second one leaves `[5, 10)`?